# Detecting multicols environment and ending it

Tags: macros, conditionals, expl3, multicol

I made a command for inputting a `.tex` file at a specific page number within the document (in the center pages of a book). It works fine except for one thing:

- If there is a `multicol` environment around the inputted `.tex` file, the `.tex` file will also be inside the same multicol environment. I want it to detect if a multicol environment is used. If it is, it should be ended and started again afterwards.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=13pt,a4paper,openany,parskip=half]{scrbook}

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{multicol}
\RequirePackage{lipsum}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
%
\RequirePackage{refcount,lastpage}
\RequirePackage{atbegshi}

\pagestyle{fancy}
% Some other commands regarding pagestyle
% is defined here.
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \g_midtsidegraf_page_total
\tl_gset:Nn \g_midtsidegraf_page_total
{ \the\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}+\int_mod:nn { 4-\int_mod:nn { \getpagerefnumber{LastPage} } {4} } {4}\relax }


\tl_new:N \g_midtsidegraf_page_after_mid
\tl_gset:Nn \g_midtsidegraf_page_after_mid
{ \the\numexpr\g_midtsidegraf_page_total / 2 + 2 \relax}


\tl_new:N \g_midtsidegraf_pagenumber_default_value
\tl_set:Nn \g_midtsidegraf_pagenumber_default_value {3}

\tl_new:N \g_midtsidegraf_pagenumber_actual_value
\tl_new:N \l__midtsidegraf_page_before_mid

\NewDocumentCommand{\midtsidegraf}{o m}
{   \IfValueTF {#1}
    { \tl_gset:Nn \g_midtsidegraf_pagenumber_actual_value {#1} }
    { \tl_gset:Nn \g_midtsidegraf_pagenumber_actual_value { \g_midtsidegraf_pagenumber_default_value } }
    \tl_set:Nn \l__midtsidegraf_page_before_mid
    { \the\numexpr\g_midtsidegraf_page_after_mid - \g_midtsidegraf_pagenumber_actual_value - 1\relax }
    \int_compare:nNnTF { \l__midtsidegraf_page_before_mid } = { \thepage }
    {\clearpage \input{#2} \clearpage}
    {}
    \int_compare:nNnTF { \the\numexpr\l__midtsidegraf_page_before_mid+\g_midtsidegraf_pagenumber_actual_value -2\relax } = { \thepage }
    {\thispagestyle{empty}}
    {}
    \int_compare:nNnTF { \the\numexpr\l__midtsidegraf_page_before_mid+\g_midtsidegraf_pagenumber_actual_value-1\relax } = { \thepage }
    {\thispagestyle{empty}}
    {}
}%
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\blankpage[1][1]{%
    \foreach \x in {1,...,#1}{%
    \clearpage
    \null
    \thispagestyle{fancy}%
    \clearpage}
}%

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{sometexfile.tex}

\section{Hello}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\end{multicols}

\newpage

\tikz[remember picture,overlay] 
\tikzset{shift={(current page.center)},xshift=0.5\paperwidth}
\node[opacity=1,inner sep=0pt]{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}};

\newpage

\tikz[remember picture,overlay] 
\tikzset{shift={(current page.center)},xshift=-0.5\paperwidth}
\node[opacity=1,inner sep=0pt]{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}};

\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{texfileno2.tex}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{multicols}

\end{filecontents}

\AtBeginShipout{%
    \midtsidegraf[3]{sometexfile.tex}
}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\begin{tabular}{l r}
    Last~Page: & \getpagerefnumber{LastPage} \\
    Rounded~total: & \g_midtsidegraf_page_total \\
    Page~after~input~command: & \g_midtsidegraf_page_after_mid \\
\end{tabular}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newpage

\blankpage[5]

\input{texfileno2}

\end{document}
```

How can I somehow detect if a `multicol` environment is being used currently and then end it if it is?

The relevant code bit is (line 42):

```
{\clearpage \input{#2} \clearpage}
```

Which I want to switch to something like:

```
{\clearpage 
\if <multicols>: 
     <save column number as n>
     \end{multicols}
\fi 
\input{#2} \clearpage 
\if <multicols>:
     \begin{multicols}{n}
\fi
}
```

The only problem is: How do I do `\if <multicols>` and `<save column number as n>`?

---

**Edit:**
I tried:

```
\makeatletter
\newif\if@multicolsarticle
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOn
...
\tl_new:N \g_midtsidegraf_column_number
...
    {
    \ifnum\numexpr\col@number>\@ne
        \@multicolsarticletrue
        \tl_gset:Nn \g_midtsidegraf_column_number { \col@number }
        \end{multicols}
    \fi
    \clearpage \input{#2} \clearpage
    \if@multicolsarticle
        \begin{multicols}{\g_midtsidegraf_column_number}
    \fi
    }
```

But it did not work.

Comment: Check if `\col@number>1`.  You might also check if the package is loaded, or `\@ifundefined(col@number}{undefined}{defined}`  If you end multicols, you will want to start it again before the file ends, or at least set a global flag for later.

Comment: @JohnKormylo it doesn't seem to work. I tried and for some reason this makes ``Lastpage`` have the value ``0`` (see edit).

Comment: How about the inputted .tex-file being nested in several enviroments, the outermost being a multicols-environment? In this case ending/restarting only the multicols-environment seems not sufficient...

Comment: @UlrichDiez yes. I'm somewhat at a loss as what to do.

Comment: @Vebjorn How about bypassing the usual output-routine while inputting the .tex-file ? (You might need to implement an output-routine for the purpose of inputting the .tex-input-file which does not interfere in bad ways with the infrastructure of the usual output-routine.Feasible, but not trivial.)

Comment: @Vebjorn Alternatively: Probably you can compile the .tex-file, which should be input, as a standalone-document into an auxiliary .pdf-file. Within your actual document use the package pdfpages for including the pages of the auxiliary pdf. Probably you need a loop for putting each page of the auxiliay pdf into a box on its own and using `\shipout` for shipping that box to the pdf-file directly, bypassing the usual output-routine. Drawback with this way: If the .tex-file to input contains cross-referencing labels and the like, those will not be available while compiling the main document.

Comment: @Vebjorn Besides this, if a pdf-file which is to be included via pdfpages contains hyperlinks and anchors/named destinations and fillable forms and the like, these things will be disabled in the .pdf-file where included stuff goes.

Comment: @UlrichDiez I think that compiling the ``.tex`` file could work. Only problem is the page numbering for the first pages of the ``.tex`` file. If one can somehow set the pagenumber to the correct value (both in the ``.tex`` file and after) it would be a viable solution.

Comment: If you intend to end the multicols, you can check if `\@currenvir` contains `multicols`.  If you have nested environments, you will have to end (and restart) all of them.

Comment: What about placing a cross-referencing-label into the main .tex-file at the place where the auxiliary pdf is to be included and in the to-be-imported .tex-file using the combination of the packages xr/xr-hyper (access cross-referencing-data from other documents) and refcount (extract text-phrases without hyperlinks from crossref-data) for within a `\setcounter{page}{...}`-directive retrieving page-number-information from that referencing-label? (Edge cases like switching between frontmatter/main-matter/backmatter so that page-counting is not always arabic might require special consideration.)

Comment: @JohnKormylo neat solution! This could solve the issue for other environments as well such as a longtable spaning multiple pages or a tcolorbox spaning multiple pages. Is it possible to save the current evironment in some variable and then do ``\end \@currenvir`` and ``\begin <variable for \@currenvir>``?

Comment: It depends on the environment.  For multicols you need the number of columns (\col@number).  Alas, not all environments save the input parameters in macros etc.